# Can I manually give mime types?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, mime-type

In my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default I have taken out the following line:

**include mime.types;**

On my website I have 2 files that are accessible (.png, .mp3). Is there a way I can manually give them each a mime type?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the default mime types should be available in `/etc/nginx/mime.types` file, you can keep whatever required. Passing manually one-by-one may be problematic for you as keeping desired type in this file can do your required job.

```
types {
text/html                             html htm shtml;
text/css                              css;
text/xml                              xml;
image/gif                             gif;
image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
application/x-javascript              js;
application/atom+xml                  atom;
application/rss+xml                   rss;

text/mathml                           mml;
text/plain                            txt;
text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
text/x-component                      htc;

image/png                             png;
image/tiff                            tif tiff;
image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
image/x-icon                          ico;
image/x-jng                           jng;
image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
image/webp                            webp;

application/java-archive              jar war ear;
application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
application/msword                    doc;
application/pdf                       pdf;
application/postscript                ps eps ai;
application/rtf                       rtf;
application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
application/x-cocoa                   cco;
application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
application/x-makeself                run;
application/x-perl                    pl pm;
application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
application/x-sea                     sea;
application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
application/x-stuffit                 sit;
application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
application/zip                       zip;

application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
application/octet-stream              deb;
application/octet-stream              dmg;
application/octet-stream              eot;
application/octet-stream              iso img;
application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
audio/mpeg                            mp3;
audio/ogg                             ogg;
audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
video/mp4                             mp4;
video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
video/quicktime                       mov;
video/webm                            webm;
video/x-flv                           flv;
video/x-m4v                           m4v;
video/x-mng                           mng;
video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
video/x-msvideo                       avi;
```

}